# How to suppress the ResponseHeader

Tags: java, security, tomcat, cors

I've Spring boot application with Spring boot, React JS, Tomcat. How do I prevent the Response header displays the originating internal server name under Response header/Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,X-Requested-With, Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:123.123.123**
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Content-Length:3494
Content-Type:image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 31 Jul 2016 06:44:54 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

This is a security issue and fails in the security review/hailstorm testing. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)? Off topic.

Comment: I'm doing according to what's in the doc but in Spring Boot. When you restrict the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to specific IPs, the IP displays in the header. want to suppress that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in an Apache configuration, or in your `.htaccess` file.

`Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "{YOUR_WEBSITE_URL}"`

Alternatively you can also add/update the header's value. [Please refer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-custom)